# phpMyAdmin Error Code 403

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, nas, synology

**System Info:**

Synology NAS 412+ 
phpMyAdmin 4.4.7 
MariaDB 5.5.43 
Files located at /volume1/web/phpMyAdmin/

**Issue description:**

Logging into phpMyAdmin I am presented with the error code 403

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 403
Error text: Forbidden
```

**Questions:**

- What file do I need to change
- Where is it located
- how do I restart the http server (if necessary) from cmd

I know it's something to do with phpMyAdmin permissions, but I just can't seem to see how or what to change.

Comment: Can you log in at all (with e.g. an administrator account)?

Comment: Yes, logging in isn't a problem. Both Admin and Root. I just can't do anything.

Comment: Check your webserver error log for hints, does it say anything?

Comment: @roi3i3ie do you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had a .htaccess file in the /web directory which had been written to by iThemes Security plugin. It had disabled all access. I just replaced this file with a fresh copy which I found on the wordpress help forum. Here's the contents should anyone want to do the same.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using Wordpress and had the same problem when accessing my phpmyadmin because of .htaccess made by iThemes Security plugin.
I fixed this error by removing the edits made by iThemes in .htaccess.

Error text:

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 403
Error text: Forbidden (rejected) It seems that the connection to server has been lost.
Please check your network connectivity and server status.
```

```
Fehler beim Bearbeiten der Anfrage
Fehlercode: 403
Fehlertext: Forbidden (rejected) 
Es scheint, dass die Verbindung zum Server verloren gegangen ist. 
Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Netzwerkverbindung und den Serverstatus.
```